# Comparison of the absolute value of an operator with its positive parts, II

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, operator-theory

Suppose $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ are self-adjoint. Does there exist a constant $C>0$ depending only on $n$ such that
$$
|A+iB| \leq C(|A| + |B|)?
$$

One can take $C=1$ if $A$ and $B$ commute.
More generally, if $A$ and $B$ are positive then this was answered in the affirmative in this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285171/comparison-of-the-absolute-value-of-an-operator-with-its-positive-parts). The argument given is not obviously extendable to this situation.

The answer to the previous question goes on to show that this inequality can never hold in infinite dimensions.